# ArrayFormula doing nothing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This problem arose several times before, but I still do not understand the behaviour. If I copy and paste the following formula throughout a column, everything is fine.

```
=sumif(ArrayFormula(text(Income!$A$2:$A,"MMM")),$A3,Income!$D$2:$D)
```

But if I wrap it with an ArrayFormula, it just does not expand. It simply keeps the same behaviour as if ArrayFormula was not there.

Comment: If you want the array formula to expand to the entire column, then specify the entire column `A3:A` in its parameters

Comment: Can you share an example of the data (or a mock copy) to test the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Sergey, the solution was to change `$A3` in the second argument of the *sumif* function to be `$A3:A`. More specifically, my final solution was the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(ArrayFormula(text(Income!$A$2:$A,"MMM")),unique(text(filter($A3:A,$A3:A<>""),"MMM")),Income!$D$2:$D))
```